# Hamiltonian constraint

Tags: general-relativity, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am having some difficulties regarding [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_constraint) wikipedia article. I can't understand why the action (for the harmonic oscilator) is written as it is.

That is, why is the Hamiltonian followed by a $\lambda$ factor?

Comment: Did you read the entire article? What is it _specifically_, that you do not understand?

Comment: @josephh Where this factor $\lambda$ comes from??

Comment: $\lambda$ is a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Answer (score 2):

When you have a constrained Hamiltonian system, you have, well, constraints --- equations of the form
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
C(q^{n},p_{n}) = 0.
\end{equation}
We multiply them by [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) to "enforce" the constraint, add them to the Hamiltonian to get a quantity that acts "like" the Hamiltonian called the **"Total Hamiltonian"**:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
H_{\mathrm{total}} = H + \lambda C(q^{n},p_{n})
\end{equation}
We use this total Hamiltonian in the action, treat the Lagrange multipliers as coordinates without conjugate momenta, and continue working happily.

**tl;dr** The $\lambda$ are [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) which enforce constraints.

**Addendum.** What is happening in the particular section you are looking at, there are two "time" dimensions:

1. a formal parameter "label time" $\tau$ (which intuitively is analogous to proper time), and
2. "coordinate time" $t$ (Newton's absolute time) now elevated to be a position variable.

Working with one spatial dimension, so we don't have to worry about indices. Our initial action is,
\begin{equation}\tag{3a}
S[q, \mathrm{d}q/\mathrm{d}t] = \int L\left(q,\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}

We parametrize position $q$ using $\tau$, and time $t$ is parametrized by $\tau$, so the action becomes,
\begin{equation}\tag{3b}
S[q(\tau), \frac{\mathrm{d}q(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}, t(\tau)] = \int L\left(q(\tau), \frac{\mathrm{d}q(\tau)/\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t(\tau)/\mathrm{d}\tau}\right) \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}t(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}\tau}_{=\,\mathrm{d}t}.
\end{equation}
Here we used the chain rule to write
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t} \mbox{“="} 
\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}\tau}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t(\tau)}
=\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}\tau}
\frac{1}{\mathrm{d}t(\tau)/\mathrm{d}\tau}
\end{equation}
If we denote differentiation with respect to $\tau$ by dots, and define
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\widetilde{L}(q,\dot{q},\dot{t}) := \dot{t}\,L\left(q,\frac{\dot{q}}{\dot{t}}\right)
\end{equation}
the OP can take as exercises proving:

**Exercise 1.** Prove the action is invariant under the symmetry for the Lagrangian, for any function of label time $f(\tau)$,
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
\widetilde{L}(q,f(\tau)\dot{q},f(\tau)\dot{t})
=f(\tau)\widetilde{L}(q,\dot{q},\dot{t}).
\end{equation}

**Exercise 2.**
It's also not hard to prove the momentum from the original Lagrangian $L[q(t),q'(t)]$ (where prime indicates differentiation with respect to $t$)
\begin{equation}\tag{7a}
p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q'(t)}
\end{equation}
when compared to $\widetilde{p}(\tau)$ the momentum with respect to $q$ in $\widetilde{L}$
\begin{equation}\tag{7b}
\widetilde{p} = \frac{\partial \widetilde{L}}{\partial \dot{q}(\tau)}
\end{equation}
are the same, i.e., satisfy
\begin{equation}\tag{8}
p = \dot{t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\dot{q}/\dot{t})}\frac{1}{\dot{t}} = \widetilde{p}.
\end{equation}

**Exercise 3.** Prove the conjugate momentum for $\dot{t}(\tau)$ in $\widetilde{L}$ is the negative Hamiltonian
\begin{align}
p_{t} &= \frac{\partial\widetilde{L}}{\partial\dot{t}} \tag{9a}\\
&= L\left(q,\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}\right) - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial L(q,\mathrm{d}q/\mathrm{d}t)}{\partial(\mathrm{d}q/\mathrm{d}t))}\tag{9b}\\
&= -H(q,\mathrm{d}q/\mathrm{d}t)\tag{9c}
\end{align}

**Exercise 4.** Verify the Hamiltonian associated with $\widetilde{L}$ may be written, using the Legendre transform, as
\begin{equation}\tag{10}
\widetilde{H} = p_{t}\dot{t} + \widetilde{p}\dot{q} - \widetilde{L}.
\end{equation}
Prove
\begin{equation}\tag{11}
\widetilde{H} = \dot{t}(H + p_{t}).
\end{equation}
And now we should begin to worry. Why? See, in Equation (9) we proved $p_{t}=-H$, and in Equation (11) we proved the Hamiltonian associated with $\widetilde{L}$ is directly proportional to $p_{t}+H$. But Equation (9) implies $p_{t}+H=0$, which means we expect $\widetilde{H}=0$. That's odd.

This is because $\widetilde{H}=0$ is a **constraint** (in the sense that, not every initial value of $t(\tau_{0})$ and $q(\tau_{0})$ and $\dot{q}(\tau_{0})$ satisfy this --- we are constrained in our choice of initial data by this constraint). And, looking at Equation (11), we see that $\dot{t}$ acts like the Lagrange multiplier enforcing this constraint.

**Parting Exercise:** Prove every Lagrangian which is Homogeneous in velocities --- i.e., satisfies Eq (6) --- will have a Hamiltonian constraint $H=0$.

Comment: **Exercise 5:** Fix any mistakes in the algebra and calculus I made.

Comment: This is an informative answer +1. I’d give another +1 for the effort/time and examples. Last time I used Lagrange multipliers in a calculation was year 4 stat mech in 1994! I had almost forgotten the justification for using them, and this answer helped. Thanks.

Comment: @josephh I'm glad to help. I was just taking notes on this very subject a couple weeks ago, and whenever I read a paper or chapter I try to extract a good set of exercises from it. Right place, right time.

Comment: **Exercise 6:** Prove *every* Lagrangian which is Homogeneous in velocities --- i.e., satisfies Eq (6) --- will have a Hamiltonian constraint $H=0$.